# mp3 upload php from android

Tags: php, android, file-upload, mp3

I am trying to upload mp3 file from my android phone to php server. I use the following code to encode it into string and then upload it using httpPost (for which I have not include the code in this post for keeping it to the point).

```
File audioStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "LEADVoices");
InputStream is;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                       

try {
    System.out.println("The name of the audio file " + audioName);
    is = new FileInputStream(audioStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + audioName);
    int bytesAvailable = is.available();
    int maxBufferSize = 1000;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];
    int bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
        bytesAvailable = is.available();
        bytesAvailable = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
    }

    System.out.println("Uploaded an audio file");
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedAudio = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);  
    choiceList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("audio",encodedAudio));
    is.close();
    baos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     System.out.println("bytearrayoutputstream error1");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();


System.out.println("bytearrayoutputstream error2");
                        }
```

On the server side, I am using the following code to decode the string. However, the mp3 files that are generated on the server side cannot be played. Anyone has any idea what is wrong?

```
                  $audio = 'myfile.mp3';
          $encodedString = $_POST['audio'];
          $dir = '../myfolder/Audios';
          if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
          }
         $decoded=base64_decode($encodedString);
         $filepath = $dir.'/'.$audio;
        file_put_contents($filepath,$decoded);
       }
```

Comment: "seem to be empty"? Did you bother actually checking? e.g. `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's coming through, and `echo strlen($decoded)`, etc...? Plus, nowhere in your android code are you actually setting a name for your POST data, so probably you don't have a `voice_recording` item in your _POST array anyways.

Comment: @Marc B see my edits, you posted this comment before I had even finished entering my post and read it myself.

Comment: Comments still hold, do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you're actually receiving.

Comment: with var_dump($_POST), I get this error message. What does it mean? <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i> <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i></pre>

Comment: That means your $_POST array is empty and your phone is not sending anything to the server properly.

Comment: Now I am getting this but still the audio does not play. It says file is corrupted: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'AAAAGGZ0eXBpc2...ZoZAAAAABTXqjBU16owQAAA+gA&#10;AANwAAEAAAEAA...AAAAAQAAAAAAA&#10;AAA...AGldHJhawAAAFx0a2hkAAAAB1NeqMFTXqjBAAAA&#10;AQAAA..A&#10;QAA...AABQW1kaWEAAAAgbWRoZAAAAABTXq...Cxo&#10;ZGxyAAAAAAAAAABzb...mYAAAAQc21oZAAA&#10;AAAAAAAAAAAAJGRpbmYAAAAcZHJlZgAAAAAAAAABAAAADHVybC'...</font> <i>(length=6096)</i>

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to use base64 to encode the file because is a very heavy task, instend use multipart form, this is an example

```
new Upload().execute(selectedPath); //path to file like /mnt/sdcard/file_name
```

And this is the Asynctask

```
private class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Start upload...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                DataOutputStream dos = null;
                DataInputStream inStream = null;
                String existingFileName = params[0];
                String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary =  "*****";
                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;
                int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
                String urlString = "your php upload page here";
                try{
                    //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName) );
                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    // Don't use a cached copy.
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);
                    // Use a post method.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
                    dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + file_name + "\"" + lineEnd); // uploaded_file_name is the Name of the File to be uploaded
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    while (bytesRead > 0){
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        //Other parameter like key=value&key1=value but you can also use list or another method
                        String[] posts = post.split("&");
                        int max = posts.length;
                        for(int i=0; i<max;i++) {
                            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                            String[] kv = posts[i].split("=");
                            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + kv[0] + "\"" + lineEnd);
                            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain"+lineEnd);
                            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                            outputStream.writeBytes(kv[1]);
                            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                     }
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException ex){
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
                catch (IOException ioe){
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                }
                //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
                try {
                    inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
                    String str;
                    String response_data = "";
                    while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null){
                        response_data = response_data+str;
                    }
                    inStream.close();
                    return response_data;
                }
                catch (IOException ioex){
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
                }

                return "";
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                  Log.i("result", result);
                  if(result.equals("ok")){
                      Toast.makeText(activity, "Upload succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }else{
                      Toast.makeText(activity, "Error on upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
              } 

        }
```

Hope it help.

Comment: i have a bunch of other stuff that I am uploading along with the audio files, and they are all being transferred to the server using namevaluepairs. That is why, I want to stick with using namevaluepairs, otherwise there is no way of knowing which of my user generated this audiofile (i will have to make a lot of changes to my code). I know that the file is being uploaded but it seems that something is wrong with the way it is being decoded. I might be missing a command or something.

Comment: I edit my answer so you can add other parameter to the request

Comment: okay, i am now uploading my files using the code provided above. However, I am running into the same problem. I am still unable to play the file. It is saying the file is corrupted.

Comment: with this code you can save it with the function move_uploaded_file specifing path and source (you have it in $_FILES), are you uploading a mp3 file or a recording file form emulator? if is a recording try with a mp3 from your computer i had the same problem with audio recording

Comment: I am using the code below to upload an actual mp3 file from android phone: <?php header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$file_name = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
$file_tmp_name = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
$target_path  = '../LEAD/Audios/'.basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $target_path)) {
 echo "The file has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "error uploading the file";
}

Comment: You receive any PHP error like: "permission denied" on move_uploalede_file, or the file is saved but corrupted? have you try to print $_FILES and see what is send from the app?

Comment: The var_dump message means that there is no value inside $_POST, and i think you should remove the header() from your PHP file

Comment: I have removed the header from php file but still unable to play. Here is the output (there is no type for the file) -- file name: VOICE_0623_1806.mp3, file temp name: C:\wamp\tmp\php1E4E.tmp, file type:

Comment: the output mentioned in the comment above is obtained in response to the following commands in the php file: echo 'file name '.$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']; echo 'file temp name '.$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']; echo ''file type '.$_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];